# MySQL compare multiple fields in a single table with 18000 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 18000 rows. This data is retrieved from different servers and, let's say, each one has 2000 rows of this grand total. All data should be equal across the servers, but actually it's not.

Let me simplify the schema to make it easy to understand:

```
table1 [ server_id, row_id, param1, param2, param3 ... param40 ]
```

So as I said, I have 2000 rows of each pair of server_id + row_id primary key, total of 18000 rows in the table.

Is it possible to compare all rows and columns then return which of the 40 parameter is different (without assuming one server as the base of comparison)?

Thanks

Comment: poor quality. pls explain

Comment: Imagine that I have 10 Firewalls in my network. Each firewall has its bunch of rules, each rule can have several parameters. The data across the Firewalls should be the same, but actually it's not. I need to find which rules in which firewall are different from the majority, by analyzing every single parameter inside the rules. Is it clear now?